# Is it possible to prevent app re-initialization in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, back-button

I am building a Cordova project that calls the Webview, and am essentially using it to display my webpage as the app.  I have tested my code on Android and the app loads fine and the page loads fine. I can surf around my site and use the hardware 'back' button to navigate back to the initial page.  But, when I get to the initial page, if I click the 'back' button again, I get the device ready screen and the app often doesn't re-initialize.  I have tested this on an Android emulator (Galaxy Nexus API 30), and on my personal Android device (Samsung Galaxy S7).

What I am wondering is if I can prevent the app from going back to the device ready screen, or force app re-initialization, so that the user doesn't get "stuck" on the device ready screen?  I have searched extensively on Duck Duck Go, Google and Stack Overflow and can't find that anyone has addressed this particular problem before.  Please note that I am fairly new to Cordova and Javascript, but am an HTML expert.

Here's the app code from my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Cordova App c15-iab</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>My Sample App</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = {
                // Application Constructor
                initialize: function() {
                    this.bindEvents();
                },
                // Bind Event Listeners
                //
                // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
                // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
                bindEvents: function() {
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
                },
                // deviceready Event Handler
                //
                // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
                // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
                onDeviceReady: function() {
                    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

                    // Add event listeners.
                    document.addEventListener("offline", goOffline, false);
                    document.addEventListener("online", goOnline, false);

                },
                // Update DOM on a Received Event
                receivedEvent: function(id) {
                    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id),
                        listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening'),
                        receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
            
                    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
                    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
            
                    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
                }
            };
            app.initialize();

            // BT next several lines of code. 20200907_1810
            function goOffline() {
                // Redirect to your local/offline page here
                document.location = 'offline.html';
            }
            function goOnline() {
                // Load the actual online content in InAppBrowser/WebView
            
                //use some really slow page for testing.  The http page has been whitelisted.
                var path="http://www.someexamplesite.com";
            
                // Using '_self' to force WebView open.
                var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(path, '_self', 'location=no');
            
                //spinner html
                var spinner ="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1'><style>.loader {position: absolute;    margin-left: -2em;    left: 50%;    top: 50%;    margin-top: -2em;    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;    border-radius: 50%;    border-top: 5px solid #3498db;    width: 50px;    height: 50px;    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes spin {  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}@keyframes spin {  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }}</style></head><body><div class='loader'></div></body></html>";
            
                //intended webpage is loaded here
                ref.executeScript({code: "(function() {document.write(\""+spinner+"\");window.location.href='"+path+"';})()"});
            
                //loadstart event
                ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                    //nothing specific needed for spinner                        
                });
            
                //loadstop event
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
                    //nothing specific needed for spinner
                });
                
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just don't serve a web-page, but make it local SPA (single page application)... then the device's back-button obviously won't be able to navigate anywhere, because there is no history. One could also load SPA remotely, but the mere issue is that this won't work while offline. That's why it should be packaged instead of fetched.

Comment: Dear Martin, being fairly new to javascript, I'm not sure I'm savvy enough to build an SPA.  Also, I'm not sure if it's appropriate, as my goal is to serve the remote webpage in my InAppBrowser, as if it was the actual app.  Do you have any other ideas?  Brian

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to intercept the backbutton event and cancel it when window.history.length is down to one.

Comment: Dear weHe, I tried adding 'document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);' to the app's onDeviceReady event, and then added the following function: [code]   function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert('window.location.history = ' + window.location.history);
    if (window.location.history == 1) {
     return false;
    }
      }[/code].  The function doesn't work, and the alert doesn't even show on my Android emulator.  On my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone, the alert only shows when the user goes back to the app initialization screen and, therefore, doesn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you catch deviceready (NOT onDeviceReady)? Log it and remotely watch the console till you have proof. I've just tested my app on android emulator and I see the 'backbutton' event fire reliably, same on my tablet. 

And it is window.history and not window.location.history; also this is an array, so check its .length==1! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Hope that helps - all the best! weHe

Comment: I ended up converting my app to a Progressive Web App.  That solved all of my problems.  Thanks for your help, though.